# How to deploy exploded war as folder in WildFly 10

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly

For my current project, I created standalone Spingboot based application. Currently I am deploying the application as war file in  WildFly standalone deployment folder.
For do any changes (like updating JNDI name) in in war file I need open the war as zip, extract it and change the application.properties file and after that package it as war.

Is there any way through which I can keep the exploded war in deployment folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Please follow below steps:

1) I am considering your war name as `project.war` explode the war file and keep the folder name as `project.war`

2) Paste the exploded `project.war` folder in deployments folder.

3) Open Wildfly\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml file in any editor

4) Search for subsystem > `deployment-scanner tag` in file once found, the add `auto-deploy-exploded="true"` parameter into it.

5) After all steps you can restart the WildFly

Comment: The tag `deployment-scanner` should be `auto-deploy-exploded="true"`

Answer (score 2):

There is one more approach to deploy exploded war/ear files, you just need to create marker file in deployment directory with name FileName.war.dodeploy

Answer (score 0):

You can also use overlays to 'replace' files in deployments. And since WildFly 12 (i think) you can use exploded managed deployments and replace files in deployments via the jboss-console and soon edit from the web console itself.